# error when starting Linux (unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sda6)

Tags: linux, initramfs, fsck

I had a problem starting my Linux, it shows this error.
I've tried different ways and it still doe[image]sn't work

Comment: I don't answer, maybe my memory is just over a year old, it doesn't make sense that it's broken.
Do you know any way I can find out if my memory is actually broken?